How can I set up a MIDI controller with Pipewire?
apologies in advance for not understanding Linux audio. I'm a musician and I just want to use it, although I don't understand cars either but I can still drive one.
I have a laptop running Lubuntu. I then installed Ubuntu Studio. I've connected an old audio interface which it surprisingly seems to understand. I can see the name of it show up on the audio configuration under output and input devices (Mbox 2) Well technically it-s an Mbox 2 Mini but that's what shows up. And it plays sound when I open up brave and youtube. I was afraid to even plug this into a linux pc knowing how incompatible everything is, however I have seen some people online use this with Linux so I decided to try it.
I havent tested audio input yet... but so far I think the audio is working fine.
The problem I'm having is with MIDI. I plugged in a MIDI controller (Alesis Q49). And as usual with Linux, nothing happens. No alert to tell you you've plugged something in or it recognises it or doesn't recognise it or whatever. Very annoying but this is a general problem with Linux.
So I've spent all morning researching and looking through the huge list of ubuntu studio programs trying to find some way to set up MIDI after 4 hours, I'm still no closer than where I was four hours ago. I might have installed, uninstalled, reinstalled some unneccessary shit too.
All of the advice is for jack or alsa or pulse or whatever and this system is trying to use pipewire. Again I don't need an explanation of whatever this shit is cos I won't understand it. Crazy how solutions posted two years ago are now outdated.
So I'm trying to use pipewire cos I heard its better for some reason. (again no need to explain why, I'm too stupid to understand). And I haven't found any software or guide or set up for MIDI instruments or anything.
How do I do this? Should I just change it back to jack or whatever?

Starting point for decisions is your release, which you haven't specified. Ubuntu and the desktop flavors didn't switch from PulseAudio to PipeWire at the same time, thus what release you were using & when you ran Ubuntu Studio installer is I believe required detail we have not been given.  FYI: Decisions written two years ago would be appropriate for 22.04 for example; but you've not said what you're using!

Not sure about that stuff. I'm probably using the latest version of Lubuntu 22 or something, and I ran ubuntu studio installer a couple of months ago. The ubuntu studio control application thing recommends pipewire and not the other options. So I'm pretty sure its from after the switch to pipewire

Specifics matter; latest would mean you're using a 2024 release; but 22.something implies you're using a release that is 4-5 releases ago from 2022; 22.04 was 5 releases ago (4 from latest), and 22.10 is EOL but was 4 releases ago (3 from latest)..

FYI:  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS did not use PipeWire, it was switched to in 22.10 for Ubuntu Desktop, and some flavors used it to (eg. Ubuntu-MATE did at 22.10), however Lubuntu/Ubuntu Studio didn't switch to PipeWire until 23.04... so specifics matter & your question including PipeWire implies a newer release than 22.04 would allow for (22.04 doesn't include PipeWire involvement unless you've very much changed your system)
